# How to hide QTabWidget bar only PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to hide PyQt5 QTabWidget Bar but widget will be visible. Anyone have some solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it with

```
    self.tabBar = self.tabWidget.findChild(QTabBar)
    self.tabBar.hide()
```